# Trying to add key in Messagebag in Request class : Laravel 5.3

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5.3

**Original Request class**

```
class LoginRequest extends Request
{

    public function wantsJson() {
        return true;
    }

    public function authorize() {
        return true;
    }

    public function rules() {
        return [
            'EmailAddress'  => 'required',
            'Password'      => 'required',
        ];
    }

    public function messages() {
        return [
            "EmailAddress.required" => trans("login.RequiredEmailAddress"),
            "Password.required"     => trans("login.RequiredPassword")
        ];
    }

}
```

**Modified Request class**

```
class LoginRequest extends Request
{

    public function wantsJson() {
        return true;
    }

    public function authorize() {
        return true;
    }

    public function rules() {
        return [
            'EmailAddress'  => 'required',
            'Password'      => 'required',
        ];
    }

    public function messages() {
        return [
            "EmailAddress.required" => trans("login.RequiredEmailAddress"),
            "Password.required"     => trans("login.RequiredPassword")
        ];
    }

    public function formatErrors(\Illuminate\Contracts\Validation\Validator $validator) {
        if($validator->fails()) {
            $validator->errors()->add('AttemptsLeft', '4 attempts left');
        }
        parent::formatErrors($validator);
    }
}
```

In the modified code, I am trying to add a key to inform user about the total attempts pending for login.

Below was the code used.

```
if($validator->fails()) {
    $validator->errors()->add('AttemptsLeft', '4 attempts left');
}
```

I am getting below error

> Argument 1 passed to
>   Illuminate\Foundation\Http\FormRequest::response() must be of the type
>   array, null given, called in
>   C:\xampp\htdocs\Projects\Projects\Laravel\vendor\laravel\framework\src\Illuminate\Foundation\Http\FormRequest.php
>   on line 117 and defined

Can you please suggest how can I make it work correctly?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You forgot to `return parent::formatErrors($validator);`